# Why do you need "traefik.docker.network" for some service?

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a docker swarm setup with traefik in it. I added a service (in this case, grafana and prometheus) with this label:

```
  grafana:
    ...
    labels:
      - "router=inbound"
      - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.rule=Host(`grafana.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.service=grafana"
      - "traefik.http.services.grafana.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
      - "traefik.docker.network=inbound"
  networks:
      - inbound

  traefik:
    ...
    command:
      - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`router`,`inbound`)
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entryPoints.http.address=:80
    networks:
      - inbound
```

Without `"traefik.docker.network=inbound"` in grafana labels, I can reach the service and access the UI, but it's incredibly unstable and I often got connection error. With that line, everything works smoothly.

I wonder what exactly that line does. Why is the service having connection issues (but not totally unreachable) without that line, when the container itself is already configured to be inside the same network as traefik router.

Answer (score 1):

## How traefik selects IP address of a service

Your example declares for the service `grafana` labels:

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.service=grafana"
      - "traefik.http.services.grafana.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
```

These labels instruct `traefik` to forward HTTP requests to port 3000 of the `grafana` service.

As docker allows each service to be connected to more than one network, the service (e.g. grafana) may have multiple network interfaces with different IP addresses.

Your HTTP service might bind to all network interfaces and others services might bind only to subset of them. The later ones will not serve HTTP service on some interfaces.

When `traefik` does not find the label:

```
      - "traefik.docker.network=inbound"
```

it asks swarm for an IP address of the `grafana` service and picks whatever comes first regardless of the network. If the address picked is not served by you service, you get timeouts - thus the random connection issues you have experienced.

On the other hand - when the label `traefik.docker.network` is present, `traefik` is more picky and takes only the IP address of the service bound to the given network. Assuming `grafana` being always bound to that network interface you get stable responses.

## Cure for services such as grafana, virtuoso and others

Many services work perfectly without that label, e.g. `whoami`, `nginx`, python web applications using `waitress` or `uvicorn` worked to us without any issue.

There are other services such as `grafana` or `virtuoso`, which might become unstable or totally unusable in docker swarm with `traefik` if not used with the `traefik.docker.network` label.

Me and my colleague Milan Holub have spent around 18 hours trying to resolve mysterious issue for `virtuoso` (responding only the first request,  changing it's IP address in the traefik dashbord...) and the `traefik.docker.network` label was the final solution.